# База музыки в Android 5.0.2. Где находится и как получить доступ?

Tags: android

Я заметил что как минимум два плеера(стандартный и JetAudio) в Android 5.0.2 используют общую базу музыки(добавляешь плейлист в одном он появляется и во втором). Поскольку я разрабатываю аудиоплеер и не вижу смысла изобретать велосипед, хочется узнать как получить к этой базе доступ.

Answer (score 1):

В `Android` есть класс `MediaStore` который дает вам доступ ко всем медиафайлам на телефоне. Работая с ним через `ContentResolver` вы можете получить все песни и плейлисты сохраненные на телефоне

[Документация по плейлистам](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.html)

Так же вот [похожий вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694909/given-an-android-music-playlist-name-how-can-one-find-the-songs-in-the-playlist) там есть примеры, как с MediaStore работать.

Чтобы получить доступ к плейлистам вам надо подключить пермишны на чтение external storage. если захотите создавать свои плейлисты и сохранять их на телефон то понадобятся и на запись.